# detect user response to the Allow Push notification dialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

Is there any way to detect what user choose when promoted with the "allow push notification" dialog?

I want to catch what user choose at the moment he tap one of the dialog buttons ("Allow" or "Don't Allow")
any why I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. While you *can* determine whether notifications are enabled (using UIApplication's `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` method), this does not tell you *why* notifications are not registered when they aren't.

It could be for any of the following reasons:

• The user has never been prompted for them.

• The user has specifically declined them.*

• The user approved them at some point, but has since turned them off.*

It's unfortunate that Apple does not provide a means to detect a user declining push notification registration when prompted. I suspect this is a conscious design decision intended to make it less likely for developers to harangue users.

I hope this helps.

(* ...you could infer which of the second and third options applies by storing a persistent flag upon the first registration, but this doesn't seem to be what you're asking for...)

Comment: If only we had, `hasDeclinedRemoteNotificiationPermission`, we could direct the user to the settings tab instead of silently calling `registerForRemoteNotifications`. I think the next best thing is to keep a flag weather we have presented the system dialog, then use a combination of the flag with the registered push token to determine weather we need to go to settings tab or present the push.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way of doing this, but I've implemented a workaround: [APNPermisionRequest](https://github.com/tilowestermann/APNPermissionRequest).

The interesting part here is to add an observer for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and then show the request. After the notification is fired (ie. the request was answered), you can check for the status using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]`.